# converting avro record to string and back

Tags: json, mapreduce, avro

I have to develop a mapreduce program that is needed to perform a join on two different data sets. 
One of them is a csv file and other is an avro file.

I am using MultipleInputs to process both sources. However to process both dataset in one single reducer, I am converting the Avro Data to Text by using

`new Text(key.datum.toString())`

My challenge is to convert the Json String generated above to Avro rcord back in reducer as the final output needs to be in avro format.

Is there a particular function or class that can be used to do this?
If yes, can you please quote an example as well?

Comment: Could you share your piece of code. ?. Have you considered using AvroJob to perform the operation all the way through to the reducer?

Comment: Hi venBigData, I have taken a different approach by serializing my csv into avro with same schema as that of the avro file.